# How to merge the Two column in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have 2  Data Table in Vb.Net

First Table `Table1` Like

Accno   ||   Name      ||   databirth

100     ||   Hema     ||    10-may-1990

200     ||  Chand    ||

300     ||  arul     ||

Second Table `table2` like

Accno          databirth

100            10-may-1990

200           23-Aug-1990

300           5-Jan-1989

But I need `Table1` like below Struture

Accno        Name           databirth

100          Hema          10-may-1990

200          Chand         23-Aug-1990

300         arul           5-Jan-1989

Answer (score -1):

```
for i as byte = 0 to Table1.Rows.count-1

 dim row as datarow = Table1.rows(i)
 dim accno as integer = row("Accno")
 dim dr() as datarow = Table2.Select("Accno=" & accno)

 if dr.lenght>0 then
    if not string.isnullorempty(row("databirth").tostring) then
        row("databirth") = dr(0)("databirth")
    end if
 end if

 next

next
```

Comment: Please consider your answer many issues within it. You have two nexts when your only using one and lenght should be length. This wont even run...